# htop gives blank screen

Tags: arch-linux, htop

Previously I was using `htop` on 32-bit Manjaro, and it worked fine, then I switched to 64-bit ArchLinux, when starting `htop` it shows a blank screen, and any key press does nothing.

I've tried to add `TERM=xterm-color htop`, but it does the same.

My current `$TERM` value is `xterm-256color`.

I've tried `extra/htop 1.0.2-2`, `aur/htop-svn 308-1` and also `aur/htop-blueweb 1.0.2-1` all give me a blank screen, anything I should do to fix this?

EDIT: additional info for ldd:

output of `ldd /usr/bin/htop`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff5ba70000)
libncursesw.so.5 => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5 (0x00007fecdc490000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fecdc188000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fecdbdd8000)
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fecdc6f8000)
```

i've tried to reinstall these packages:

```
core/glibc
multilib/lib32-glibc
core/ncurses
```

but there are no luck

EDIT2: found out using `strace` that there are some program that causes `htop` to hang, after restarting the computer, problem solved..

Comment: Have you tried exporting TERM=xterm-color before running htop?

Comment: "some program that causes htop to hang, after restarting the computer, problem solved" I ran into this same condition today. I noticed that `top` also hung. In fact I'm still running now, haven't rebooted yet. Ubuntu System Monitor still works. It started happening after swap filled up while running my build. Now the computer is back but top/htop hang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is either with your display setup or `htop` itself. To eliminate that it's an issue with `htop` can you attempt to redirect its output to a file?

```
$ htop > htop_dump.txt
```

After running this then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. If there's content in the file, `more htop_dump.txt`, then the issue likely lies with your screen setup in your terminal/shell.

If on the otherhand this file also shows nothing, then something is broken in your system's setup, either with a library that `htop` depends on, or `htop` the binary itself.

You might also want to attempt to run an `strace` to see if there's a resource/configuration file that `htop` is pulling in that's hosing it's display. Something like this:

```
$ strace -o htop_strace.log -s 2000 htop
```

Comment: the redirect command was outputing `[?1049h[1;49r(B[m[4l[?7h[?1h=[?25l[39;49m[?1000h`

Comment: the strace command outputing: http://pastie.org/8694342 <-- only few last line copied.. there no more output after those lines

Comment: @Kokizzu - OK so it's an issue with your terminal/shell then (based on that test). You could see if there is some stray command from your shell's config files causing issue by opening up a "clean" shell, `bash --noprofile --norc`.

Comment: @Kokizzu - just saw the strace output, yeah that doesn't look right at all. Is it hanging on the `read(...` in the output of `strace`?

Comment: nope, still blank screen, and `Ctrl+C` has no effect, just like before, i had many stray `htop` processes that could not be killed XD

Comment: yes, there are no more output after `read(...`

Comment: @Kokizzu - I think I would be very suspicious then of some form of corruption within my system. Disk failures and/or a lower level file may have been corrupted. `htop` looks to be reading something but is just hanging on it.

Comment: yes, there are program with pid 12366 that could not be accessed at all `/proc/12366/cmdline` that makes every command hangs (including `ps`)

Comment: lemme try this again after restarting..

Comment: @Kokizzu - def. sounds like a hardware issue to me. I had a Fedora Core 3 system a while back that appeared fine until I tried to access a sub directory under /var/lib. Then it would hang and I couldn't kill the processes accessing this directory. Turned out to be a failing HDD.

Comment: chromium was the problem (pid 12366), after restarting htop works fine ^^; i'll mark this as solved, thanks for the suggestion to use `strace` to find out the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was using "**/usr/bin/konsole**". The $TERM variable was set to "Linux" for this.
 
htop did not work in this case. 

When htop was invoked from **"/usr/bin/gnome-terminal"**, it worked fine, the $TERM variable was set to "xterm" in this case.
So when I changed the $TERM to "xterm" from "Linux" for "konsole", it worked.

Running: 
Linux {hostName} 2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Oct 9 17:27:49 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When htop failed, $XTERM was set to "Linux", the last lines in my strace were as following (in case it is useful):

`stat("/dev/vc/0", 0x7ffffaff2710)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/dev/tty0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(4, 0), ...}) = 0
getpid()                                = 88481
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/61", 4095) = 11
open("/dev/pts/61", O_WRONLY)           = 3
ioctl(3, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=55, ws_col=228, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)        = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/gpmctl"}, 13`