# Running Script via Crontab With Different Result?

Tags: grep, cron, root, htop

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/echo q | /usr/bin/htop -C | /usr/bin/aha --line-fix | /usr/bin/html2text -width 999 | /usr/bin/grep -v "F1Help\|xml version=" > htop.txt
```

It just captures the `htop` output.

It works fine if I run the script via command line but then if I run it via `crontab` as root:

```
15 15 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /root/collect_system_stats.sh
```

htop.txt will have just 1 byte and `hexdump` shows:

```
0000000 000a                                   
0000001
```

What I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use grep with the  `--line-buffered`  flag, otherwise grep exits after the first match. I don't have a full qualified explanation for this, but that's what made my script work in a similar case.

Found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562344/what-does-grep-line-buffering-do) to line-buffer for grep.

Installing a cronjob as root user with htop can result in a error message:

```
/usr/bin/htop -C Error opening terminal: unknown
```

Setting `TERM=xterm` in the script can resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My understanding is that `grep` will grep line by line regardless of the match result.  I just added `--line-buffered`, and I will report back in 20 hours.  Thanks!

Comment: The link I pasted says "[...] most standard commands, include grep, buffer the output, meaning it does not write data immediately to stdout. It collects large amount of data (depend on OS, in Linux, often 4096 bytes) before writing."

Comment: I thought before exit, it would flush everything.  I thought `--line-buffered` was for people to see quick result (e.g. grepping 1 character in few terabyte of data and such character exists at the beginning).

Comment: The cronjob just kicked in.  Didn't work :(  Thanks tho :)

Comment: I just saw that you use only `> htop.txt`, this way your file will get replaced everytime you run the script. In addition to the missing `--line-buffer` the result is exactly what I would expect. You should just append the new output to file: `>> htop.txt` should do it. For tests you could just add a new line in the cronjob to run every minute or so, so you don't have to wait a day for the results.

Comment: Thanks for following up.  `/root/collect_system_stats.sh` always does `mkdir -p \`date '+%d/%m/%Y/%H%M%S'\`` first and then `cd` into the folder and then run that command line.  Hence, `> htop.txt` is fine in my case.  Good catch tho :)

Comment: I changed to what you suggested `/usr/bin/echo q | /usr/bin/htop -C | /usr/bin/aha --line-fix | /usr/bin/html2text -width 999 | /usr/bin/grep --line-buffered -v "F1Help\|xml version=" > htop.txt`.  Same result -- 1 byte file generated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it with the exact same commands, resulting in a mail in /var/mail/root, saying: `+ /usr/bin/htop -C
Error opening terminal: unknown.`

I ran the crontab with bash -x. The result was the same as yours, 1 byte file size of htop.txt. Can you check if this happens in your case, too?
After googling the error I added a line to the script: `export TERM=xterm` and then I get a htop output, although it's shorter than it is when I run it manually. So you'd probably have to figure out which TERM you have to use, if that applies here.

Comment: I am on CentOS 7.  I don't see `/var/mail/root` but other users'.  But they are all empty anyway.  `echo $TERM` outputs `xterm-256color`.

Comment: I just googled as well.  [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112229/htop-gives-blank-screen) is similar to what I ran into but not exact as if I run htop, I don't see blank.  If I run `htop > file` from command line, it is okay as well.  The problem only occurs if it runs from `crontab`.

Comment: I did another test.  I think I found the issue -- `TERM` is set to `dumb` in root's `crontab`.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration.  It is indeed related to `TERM` env variable.  Could you update your answer and then I will accept it?  Putting `TERM=xterm` prior to my cron fixes the issue.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the feedback! I'm glad it works as required.